# Conditions for validity of a robust-error-variance Poisson regression

Tags: regression, self-study, poisson-regression, robust-standard-error

A variant of a Poisson regression called the "robust-error-variance Poisson regression" is an approach adapted for binary data, specially as an alternative to the logistic regression. What are the conditions of validity that are needed to apply a "robust error variance Poisson regression"? Or in other words, are there any number of assumptions that must be met before doing such a model?

**References:**

Guangyong Zou, A Modified Poisson Regression Approach to Prospective Studies with Binary Data, Am. J. Epidemiol. (2004) 159 (7): 702-706 doi:10.1093/aje/kwh090

Comment: Can you clarify the situation that lies behind your question? In what sense do you mean "validity"? What specific model do you mean by "robust error variance Poisson regression"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a useful discussion by Lumley and colleagues "Relative risk regression in medical research: models, contrasts, estimators, and algorithms" available [here](http://www.bepress.com/uwbiostat/paper293) which despite the title is not exclusive to medical research.

As I understand it the main problem with the Poisson working model is that it is capable of giving predicted probabilities greater than 1. The other main competitor, the log-binomial does not do that. Whether you see this as a problem with the algorithm or a problem with using relative risks where the baseline risk is high is a matter for your decision I think.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @mdewey's answer

The issue with maximum likelihood is that it constrains fitted probabilities to be at most 1, which can give x-outliers extremely high influence on the results. As a consequence, the estimator takes some effort to compute reliably, and its distribution might not be close to Normal

Any estimator that avoids the outlier-sensitivity of the MLE *must* do so by allowing fitted probabilities greater than 1, as the Poisson working model does. Reasonable people can disagree on whether that's a good tradeoff.

One important reason for picking the Poisson working model over other alternatives to the MLE (such as nonlinear least squares) is partly aesthetic: it approximates the MLE well when the fitted probabilities are small.  This allows the same estimator to be used for rare and common events.